# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jsonName' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Maybe you have seen this in somewhere, but my problem is about something different - it is about other websites I visit that I don't maintain.

For example website [Toast UI](https://ui.toast.com/tui-grid/) or [React Training](https://reacttraining.com/blog/) (and a lot of others, which I can't remember now). When I visit website like this, I can't use their menu links (Toast UI) - everything that has to work with javascript (mainly React).

So I opened devtools and found our this error - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jsonName' of null` which is going from line `loader.addDataPaths({[window.page.jsonName]: window.dataPath});`.

But why? These are not hidden or unknown website, it can't be like they just forget about something in code, since it is not a single website problem. So - is it problem with my computer (latest Win10)? Or browser (latest Chrome)?

Sorry if this is wrong place to ask, but I don't know other places for problem like that.

Comment: This is not a programming question.  StackOverflow is for programming questions.  You are asking a _user_ question....

Comment: @cale_b so the place is...?

Comment: ", it can't be like they just forget about something in code" ... the suggestion that live code can never have bugs, that no-one could ever overlook an issue, is noble, but unfortunately nowhere near reality, even for the best programmers :-)

Comment: @ADyson I know, but it is always same problem, maybe it is in package... But I don't understand how no one tried it. Do mentioned websites work for you or it's just me?

Comment: The sites work for me just fine.  I'm guessing that you may have an extension or other browser feature that may be causing the issue.  (I checked the dev console, and the errors you mentioned do not appear when I visit)

Comment: I get no errors on those sites either (latest Chrome, Windows 10). Unless there's some specific action we need to take to trigger it? I tried playing with the menus, since you mentioned those, and had no problems. If you're getting the exact same error in multiple sites, it does potentially indicate a problem with an extension or something. The stack trace in the console should help you see where the error originated, so that might provide a clue. Or you could try disabling your extensions one by one and see if that helps.

Comment: Sorry for late response, but I found out it works when I disabled "Anti-Adblock Killer | Reek" in tampermonkey... I never thought this could break it.

Comment: I had a similar issue on a different website that is also using gatsby. And same fix worked for me as well, i.e. Disabling "Anti-Adblock Killer | Reek" tampermonkey userscript. You should add this as an answer.